# Spring Boot Maria DB Connection | Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, mariadb

I wanted to add a mariaDB Database connection to my spring Boot application.

I definied the application.properties like this:

```
#mariaDB Connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/database
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

but i get The following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Database dependencies

```xml
        <!-- ===============
             == MariaDB
             =============== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

Does someone has any idea, what i need to change, that the connection will work?

Comment: It might have something to do with your dependencies. Can you upload your pom.xml?

Comment: @BarHoshen I added the dependencies for mariaDB and for the data-jpa is that enough? or do you want the hole pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the version of your mariadb driver, i would bet you have used springframework guru's guide. That guide uses springboot 1.4.4, so my second bet would be that your problem is a version mismatch.
If you are using springboot parent 3.X.X, I recommend you try mariadb java client version 3.1.4/3.1.0.